# How to use global variable in perl?

Tags: perl, global-variables

I will write a pseudo code

```
f1 {
..
..
if (count==1) {
count=0;// set it back to 0
return $variable;
}


f2
{
count=1;
var2=f1(..); // 
}
```

ie. if f1 is called from f2 alone, I want the f1 to return a variable. otherwise no need. I want to achieve this using global variable. can u help . or is there any other way also? 
Thanx in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Global variables aren't recommended because they make the code harder to maintain.

Comment: Why don't you pass a parameter to the function?

Comment: You should *always* return `$variable` from `f1` and ignore it if it isn't needed.

Comment: @Borodin maybe he returns something else if the caller isn't `f1`... (I agree that regardless, it's an unusual design)

Comment: @Dada: They say *" if f1 is called from f2 alone, I want the f1 to return a variable. otherwise no need"* which implies that no value is returned unless `f1` has been called from `f2`. Of course we can only guess, but there's no point in saving a `return` statement, and it's an economy only worthwhile if there's a significant amount of processing done to generate the returned value. There's always the option of checking `wantarray` as well.

Comment: @Borodin indeed. I've updated my answer with your suggestion to always return something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using global variables is usually a bad idea, as they make the code harder to maintain (as mentioned by @choroba in the comments) and to write.

As mentioned by @Borodin, if `f1` should only `return` something if called by `f2` and nothing otherwise, the simplest is to let `f1` return something, regardless of whether it was called by `f2` or not, and just ignore that return value if you are not in `f2`.

If however, `f1` needs to return a special value when called from `f2`, and something else when called from somewhere else, there are several possibilities: You could pass a parameter to `f1` that would identify who called it. Or you could use [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) to know who called `f1`. Or, if you really want to, you can use a global variable. Bellow are examples of each way.

(You can replace my `say` with your `return`.)

---

Using `caller`:

```
use strict; 
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

sub f1 {
    my $caller = (caller(1))[3];
    if ($caller && $caller eq 'main::f2') {
        say "Called from f2";
    } else {
        say "Not called from f2";
    }
}

sub f2 {
    f1();
}

f1();
f2();
```

`caller` returns an array containing information about where the current function was called from (line, package, function, etc.). The 4th element of this array is the function who called it, fully qualified with its package, hence the use of `main::f2` and not just `f2`.

---

Using an additional parameter:

```
use strict; 
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

sub f1 {
    my $caller = shift // '';
    if ($caller eq 'f2') {
        say "Called from f2";
    } else {
        say "Not called from f2";
    }
}

sub f2 {
    f1('f2');
}

f1();
f2();
```

In this example, the parameter to `f1` is optional. However, if `f1` has other parameters, you might consider making it non-optional.

---

Using a global variable :

```
use strict; 
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

our $f1_flag = 0;

sub f1 {
    if ($f1_flag == 1) {
        say "Called by f2";
    } else {
        say "Called outside f2";
    }
}

sub f2 {
    local $f1_flag = 1;
    f1();
}

f1();
f2();
```

You'll noticed that I renamed your `$count` for `$f1_flag`: it's already bad enough to have global variables, so better try to give them significant names. (That way, you shouldn't have to much trouble knowing what this variable is for, and you probably won't be tempted to reuse the same name for another variable).

[`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) declares a global (or package) variable. Then, instead of setting it to `1` inside `f2`, and then back to `0` inside `f1`, I prefer to use [`local`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html): `$f1_flag` will be `1` for every function or instruction inside the dynamic scope of `f2`.

Comment: You could also base on context. `if (defined(wantarray)) { ... }`